# Free Vehicle Database including ground clearance data

Tags: data-request, transportation, cars

I'm searching for a freely available database of vehicles sold during the last 10 years (or more) which stores technical specifications including the [ground clearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ride_height). The only database I was able to find was the [Canadian Vehicle Specifications (CVS)](http://www.carsp.ca/research/resources/safety-sources/canadian-vehicle-specifications/) but this lacks information about the ground clearance.

**Is there a free database available which also includes information about the ground clearance?**

Answer (score 0):

I think i already have given a link in another post about free car specs - hope it would not be a huge "no-no" to mention it again. Now, i will link to my most frequent stop for automotive data, because the info is free and has a lot of makes/models and other details which i need on a monthly basis - [free vehicle database](https://www.auto-data.net/en/allbrands). Must warn you, that it is mostly for the EU market. The "ground clearance" parameter here is called ride height- so when you go to a particular model look for the "ride height" section of the table. 
If you are looking for data to download free - i think [Edmund's api](http://edmunds.mashery.com/docs/read/The_Vehicle_API) may do the job. I have used it, too, but it was long ago - now i have no idea if it is still being updated and free to use.